# Moving Eclipse into Applications on MacOS

Tags: mac, installation, eclipse

I'm new in OS X, and recently I have downloaded Eclipse in it.

I want to use this Eclipse like other apps as appears in Applications in OS X.

But how to do that.

Although by copy-pasting the entire eclipse package folder only makes a folder in Applications but not like what other apps looks like.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 11):

If you want to move your `eclipse` folder into Applications, then by all means, do it. You do not have to copy the folder – just drag it wherever you want.

In OS X, it doesn't matter where applications are. You can put them wherever you like.

[image]

Inside, you'll find `Eclipse.app`, which you can run as an application. It's not uncommon for the actual `.app` files to reside in some subfolders of `/Applications`.

Comment: Zipped install file, custom installer, stores .app in a folder. It's quite evident nobody who develops eclipse has ever used a Mac.

Answer (score 2):

A simple Google search stating "eclipse in mac installation" gave me the following page:

http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~cs5/install/eclipse-osx/

The following are the contents of the page, excluding pictures, treated to conform to actual information:

Note that the *tutorial* assumes you're using Eclipse as a Java IDE. If you use Eclipse for any other programming language, adapt as needed.

> 1. Go to http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/ to download a copy of eclipse.
>
>    Search for "Eclipse IDE for Java Developers". On the right is a green, downward-pointing arrow. Next to that are links labeled "Mac OS X 32 Bit" and "Mac OS X 64 Bit." Click on the "Mac OS X 32 Bit" link. (Even if you have nice, new 64-bit Mac, it should run the 32-bit version just fine.)
>
>    After pressing the download button a page will appear telling you what is the location from where you are downloading a file (usually it is a fileserver or an academic institution hosting the file). Press the download button (a green arrow pointing downwards) and download the package.
> 2. The download will go to your Downloads folder. You will normally have an icon for the Downloads folder on the right-hand side of the dock. Find your downloaded package folder in your Downloads folder, and drag it to the Desktop. Then double-click it. You will see a folder named "eclipse".
> 3. Drag the "eclipse" folder into your Applications folder. The easiest way to do so is to open a new window in the Finder and click on Applications in the list you get on the left-hand side. Then drag the "eclipse" folder in with the other applications. Make sure that you do not drag it into a folder that's already within Applications. In other words, when you're done, the Applications folder should have directly within it a folder named "eclipse".
>
>    3.1. (This step is not required, but it's strongly recommended.) Double click the "eclipse" folder. You'll see an application named "Eclipse";
>      it has a purple icon with white horizontal stripes. Drag it into your
>      dock. Now you will be able to launch Eclipse by clicking on the icon
>      in the dock.
> 4. You may now drag your downloaded package folder to the Trash. Empty the Trash whenever you wish.
> 5. When you launch Eclipse for the first time, you'll be asked "'Eclipse' is an application downloaded from the Internet. Are you sure you want to open it?" Click "Open."
> 6. You'll see a window asking where your workspace is located. You can choose whatever place you want for your workspace, but it's easiest to just use the default you're given. I recommend that you just click the checkbox next to "Use this as the default and do not ask again" and then click "OK."
> 7. Click on the folded-over arrow on the right. You won't see this screen again, even if you quit Eclipse and relaunch it.
> 8. Now you'll see a screen with lots of buttons and panes, but nothing of consequence. You have now installed Eclipse!

Answer (score 1):

After sometime trying to do the same, I made some changes in the eclipse.ini file, and they worked.
Hours later, I found this link, with the instructions to do that (the same changes I did on my own):

[Repack eclipse for Mac OSX](http://blog.mstaessen.be/2013/01/29/repack-eclipse-for-mac-os-x/)

Basically:
In the Terminal, **go to the eclipse uncompressed folder** and do the following:

- edit `Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/eclipse.ini` and replace both lines starting with `../../../plugins` to make them start with `./plugins`
- `mv Eclipse.app /Applications`
- `mv * /Applications/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS`

Comment: @hopelessn00b Thank you. It was my first reply ever.

Answer (score 1):

You can use symlink and leave the folder in Downloads. It's just one line.

```
$ ln -s ~/Downloads/eclipse/Eclipse.app /Applications/eclipse
```

This creates a symlink named `eclipse`. When you click `Application` folder on Dock and press <kbd>E</kbd>, a eclipse icon (with small arrow for shorcut) will appear.

Answer (score 1):

Click on finder-->select remote disc-->type eclipse on search bar-->open eclipse folder by double clicking on it-->move eclipse to application by dragging it-->You'll have it ready at the application.

Note :I am on Mac OS high sierra, could be different for other OS.

Answer (score 1):

After installing Eclipse, I found `~/eclipse/` and moved it to `/Applications/eclipse`.

Strange it doesn't go there by default!